# Can we Scan more than 50000 record using SOSL query

Tags: sosl

As mentioned in Salesforce doc that it can return 2000 records  but what about scanning 500K records.

Is there any limit on records that will be scanned.

Answer (score 3):

SOSL doesn't scan anything. It leverages the system's indexes to find results. It doesn't matter if there are five records or five hundred million records, it will return the first set of most relevant records. Records not yet indexed (usually within a few seconds to minutes of creation) will not be scanned or searchable.